# Getting "Statement missing ; in function main()" even though I have the semicolon already in C++

Tags: c++

Here's the code assignment.

```
A bank charges $10 per month plus the following check fees for a commercial checking account:

$0.10 each for fewer than 20 checks
$0.08 each for 20-39 checks
$0.06 each for 40-59 checks
$0.04 each for 60 or more checks
The bank also charges an extra $15.00 if the balance of the account falls below $400 (before any check fees are applied). Write a program named lab2 that inputs for the beginning balance and the number of check written from the transaction file. Compute and display the bank's service fees for the month.

Input Validation: Do not accept a negative value for the number of checks written. If a negative value is given for the beginning balance, display an urgent message indicating the account is overdrawn. 
The program should have a loop execution of six times for reading data from a file named  transaction.txt.
Click the link transaction.txt download the file and store it in  folder c:\cis180\lab2. The file transaction.txt contains the beginning balance and number of checks written for six transactions. 
Here is the content of the file.
```

The text file

```
-100.00 -beginningbalance
30  - number of checks
400.00
-20
300.00
36
300.00
47
350.00
5
300.00
70
```

My code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sstream>
//include a library file to input data from file
using namespace std;
bool isNumeric(string pszInput);
int main()
{//start

// Constants

int numChecks; // Number of checks written for the month
double acctBalance; // Account balance before subtracting check fees
double checkFee; // Fee based on number of checks written
double totalFees; // Total monthly bank fees

ifstream inputFile;
//Open the file
inputFile.open("c:\\cis180\\transaction.txt"); 
//Initialize month counter
int transaction = 0; //first month

//Create a loop to execute 6 times. Each time the loop body reads the beginning balance and number of checks for six transaction, calculate the bank fees, display the beginning balance, number of checks, and the bank fees.
inputFile >> acctBalance;

// Display the beginning balance 
   if (acctBalance>0)
   {
   cout<<"Your beginning balance is: "acctBalance << endl; 
   }
   else (acctBalance<0)
   {
   cout<<"Your account is overdrawn!" << endl; 
   } 

// Display the number of checks that were written.
   if (numChecks>0)
   {
   cout<<"The number of checks written were: "numChecks<<endl;
   }
   else (numChecks<0)
   {
   cout<<"Number of checks must be 0 or more."<<endl; 
   }


// Determine whether the account is overdrawn.

// Validate number of checks written.

// If the number of checks is less than 0

{ // numChecks is valid, so we can calulate the fees.
// Calculate checkFee - Use if/else if structure
const double MONTHLY_FEE= 10.00; // Base monthly fee
const double MIN_BAL= 400.00; // minimum balance
const double LOW_BAL_FEE= 15.00; // extra fee for low balance
for (int transaction = 0; transaction <=6; transaction++);


   if (numChecks<20)
   {
   checkFee=(0.1*numChecks)+MONTHLY_FEE<<endl;
   }
   else if (numChecks<40 )
   {
   checkFee=( 0.08*numChecks)+MONTHLY_FEE<<endl;
   }
   else if (numChecks<60 )
   {
   checkFee=( 0.06*numChecks)+MONTHLY_FEE<<endl;
   }
   else (numChecks>60 )
   {
   checkFee=( 0.04*numChecks)+MONTHLY_FEE<<endl;
   }



// Calculate totalFees
   if (numChecks<20 && acctBalance<MIN_BAL)
   {
   totalFees=checkFee+LOW_BAL_FEE<<endl;
   }
   else if (numChecks<40 && acctBalance<MIN_BAL)
   {
   totalFees=checkFee+LOW_BAL_FEE<<endl;
   }
   else if (numChecks<60 && acctBalance<MIN_BAL)
   {
   totalFees=checkFee+LOW_BAL_FEE<<endl;
   }
   else if (numChecks>60 && acctBalance<MIN_BAL)
   {
   totalFees=checkFee+LOW_BAL_FEE<<endl;
   }
   else (numChecks<20 && acctBalance>MIN_BAL)
   { 
   totalFees=checkFee
   }


// Display results: The bank fee

cout<<"The bank fee this month is "<<totalFees<<endl;

}//end  the  loop


return 0;
}//end
```

And the errors I'm getting when I try to compile.

```
Error E2379 lab3.cpp 33: Statement missing ; in function main()
Error E2379 lab3.cpp 36: Statement missing ; in function main()
Warning W8004 lab3.cpp 115: 'transaction' is assigned a value that is never used in function main()
```

So basically my only problem is already in the title. Can anyone help out? Also I'm new to the C++ language so please be gentle. And if there's any other problems can you point it out to me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `cout<<"Your beginning balance is: "acctBalance << endl;` seems to be missing a `<<` between the leading string and `acctBalance`. And `else (acctBalance<0)` appears to be missing an `if`, as in `else if`. Likewise with `else (numChecks<0)`. [Here, have a language reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language)

Comment: You have numerous errors as already mentioned here is another: `totalFees=checkFee` needs trailing semi-colon: `totalFees=checkFee;`

Comment: The semicolon in `for (int transaction = 0; transaction <=6; transaction++);`  is one issue.

Comment: _"But now I have another problem, the output isn't right."_ That's another and new question. Don't let your question behave like a chamelion.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the operators here

```
cout << "Your beginning balance is: " << acctBalance << endl;
                                      ^^
```

and here

```
cout << "The number of checks written were: " << numChecks << endl;
                                              ^^
```

Why are you including stdlib.h? I don't see where you are you are using it. If you need this header I'd recommend [cstdlib](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/) instead.

As already pointed out in the comments you also made a semicolon instead of `{` which appears a few lines before in your code. Please consider spacing out your operators like this:

```
if(numChecks < 20) {

}
```

Using a consistent indention style would also improve readability.